# how to load 10 record in tableview from webservice in ios?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

load 10 data from server in iphone sdk with images so please explin me like

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView{
//NSLog(@"lastContentOffset: %d",(int)aScrollView.contentOffset.y);
if (lastContentOffset < (int)aScrollView.contentOffset.y) {
    NSArray *visibleRows;
    NSIndexPath *path;

    visibleRows = [tblStream visibleCells];
    UITableViewCell *lastVisibleCell = [visibleRows lastObject];
    path = [tblStream indexPathForCell:lastVisibleCell];

    //NSLog(@"last cell: %d",path.row);
    //NSLog(@"self.titlearray.count: %d",self.titlearray.count);

    if(path.row+1 == arrFeedback_Info.count){
        increment = (int)arrFeedback_Info.count;
        increment =increment+10;
        [self performSelector:@selector(Feedback_XML) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    }
}
else if (lastContentOffset > (int)aScrollView.contentOffset.y) {

}
}
```

Comment: what format used in your webservice ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this in your numberofrow selection code before that u need to get the data one by one using for loop and then u change the code in row section

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return data.count;
   }
```